# Emacs TRAMP per host custom path

Tags: emacs, path, tramp

I am using TRAMP to work on a remote host that has a very weird PATH. I was wondering whether it was possible to customize the PATH used by TRAMP to find the binary files *only* for this host?
Now, I'm using:

```
(add-to-list 'tramp-remote-path "/some/weird/path/bin")
```

but it also applies to any other host without this funky PATH, thus messing up all the other hosts' PATHs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sorry, but this is not possible yet. There is an item on Tramp's todo list for supporting connection-local variables, but this is not implemented yet.

Alternatively, you might set this in the $PATH env variable in your remote .profile. Then you instruct Tramp to use this, by adding `tramp-own-remote-path` to `tramp-remote-path`.

Comment: So `tramp-own-remote-path` is containing the $PATH found by reading the remote .profile? Could I use such a trick if my $PATH is created in a .bashrc file (or .zshrc)?

Comment: Yes, `tramp-own-remote-path` is supposed to insert your $PATH. This trick needs a remote shell which supports the  `-l` argument for invoking a login shell. If this doesn't work for you, the very recent Tramp knows another trick via the $ENV environment. This would require the development sources of Tramp or Emacs.